# HMM matching a string as mosaic of two strings from a larger panel

Tags: hidden-markov-model, bioinformatics

I have a problem which I think can be solved by an appropriately structured (“constrained?) HMM, but I’m not sure how to structure it, and what the prior art is. Any help such as implementations, relevant keywords, pointers to online material or paper references, etc. would be most welcome.

Basically, I have a huge corpus of lines of text (a “reference panel” of say, a million sentences all of the same length). I have a separate single focal sentence of the same length which is made of a mosaic of just two (arbitrarily chosen) target lines from the reference panel, copied with some errors. There is a fixed probability of the focal sentence switching between the two targets. I want to find the two targets in the reference panel which were used to make the focal sentence, and the switch points between them. I think this can be done relatively efficiently via an HMM running from left to right, and using the Viterbi algorithm. The states would be the two target lines, and the observations the focal sentence.

I have previously helped to implement an HMM in which the focal sequence is a composed of a mosaic of *any* of the sentences in the reference panel, and the hidden state is the current target. In the example above, however, I want to switch between only two targets, so I need to store the previous target in the hidden state somehow (i.e. the hidden state is quadratic in the reference panel size). However, I can increase efficiency by constraining the search path once a switch has occurred, as I only need to look at matching between the current target and the previous target. I’m not sure how to implement this efficiently, or if it’s been done before. I’m also not sure what the correct terminology is for this kind of problem, so I’m not sure what to search for.

You may recognise this as a bioinformatics problem, where a DNA sequence is composed of a mix of reference sequences, and an HMM called the Li and Stephens model is used to find a “copying path” through the reference sequences. However, the Li and Stephens model assumes that the focal sequence is a mosaic of *any* of the reference sequences, whereas I want to constrain it to be a mosaic of just two of them.